# Wordpress uses predefined number of characters; doesn't use more tag

Tags: wordpress, tags

My new WordPress site is using a predefined number of characters on its front page instead of allowing me to use the  tag where I see fit. How can I resolve this? I understand it is against policy to post my url, but if you could find a way to help me it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about the post excerpts?

Comment: See the following screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ncEQBmR.jpg

Comment: I want a more tag, rather than a predefined number of characters + elipsis

Comment: It's not against policy to post your URL ... maybe since it's your first post in here; I forgot how it is for noobs.  But you can just post the domain dot com or something. And you might want to post in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ and be more clear about what you're posting about.

Answer (score 0):

Is WordPress truncating before your `more` tag?  If so, you could try increasing the excerpt length with the [excerpt_length](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length) filter.  Just have it return a suitably high number of words.

As the codex says, make sure you use a high priority (eg 999, as in the example) to make sure your filter runs after any others.